# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a super basic evolution simulator to generate ten random "creatures" that are each a number value and then give them a random "mutation" but it keeps throwing me this error: "for i in range(creatures):
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

```
import random
from random import randint

creatures = (random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10))

print(creatures)

for i in range(creatures):
    mutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    newEvolution = creatures[i] + mutation

print("New evolution", newEvolution)
```

Answer (score 3):

creatures is a `tuple` and `range` is looking for an integer. To iterate over a tuple, just do:

```
for c in creatures:
    mutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    newEvolution = c + mutation
```

Comment: Thanks for not promoting the anti-pattern of `for i in range(len(someseq)):` with explicit indexing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the range of the length of the creatures.

```
from random import randint
creatures = (random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10))
print(creatures)
for i in range(len(creatures)): # iterate over the range of the lenght of the creatures 
    mutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    newEvolution = creatures[i] + mutation
print("New evolution", newEvolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

The creatures is a tuple and range() function as an argument takes integers.

```
Syntax for range:
range([start], stop[, step])

start: Starting number of the sequence.
stop: Generate numbers up to, but not including this number.
step: Difference between each number in the sequence.

Note that:
All parameters must be integers.
```

---

the solution:

```
import random
creatures = random.sample(range(1, 11), 10)
print(creatures)

newEvolution = []
for i in range(len(creatures)):
    mutation = random.randint(1, 2)
    newEvolution.append(creatures[i] + mutation)

print("New evolution", newEvolution)
```